# Does serverSessionTimeout and wl.realm.expiration.XYZ affects each others?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on MobileFirst 7.1 application. I found that `worklight.properties` has the following attributes:

```
###
serverSessionTimeout=86400
###
wl.realm.expiration.directUpdate=3600
wl.realm.expiration.remoteDisable=300
wl.realm.expiration.deviceAutoProvisioning=3600
wl.realm.expiration.deviceNoProvisioning=3600
wl.realm.expiration.antiXSRF=3600
wl.realm.expiration.authenticity=3600
wl.realm.expiration.anonymousUser=3600
```

So I was asking if the `serverSessionTimeout` affects/override any of the `wl.realm.expiration` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm expiration: Assuming you have successfully logged-in to a realm, that’s how long you’ll stay logged into that realm.

Session timeout: once reached, a timeout will erase all state data. However note that session timeout refreshes itself at every request, while aa realm's expiration time is not affected by requests.

The two aren't related.